# Alternative to Helvetica Rounded corners

Tags: web-fonts, font-recommendation

There are several helvetica alternative questions here, but they don't do the trick.

Rounded corners helvetica has letters that are slightly slimmer than regular helvetica and it has rounded tips instead of square shaped tips at line ends.

I've been trying to find alternative for web (i need to generate web fonts but apparently adobe has asked fontsquirrel not do give out helvetica fonts) and so far my search has yielded me nothing, despite going through several free font sites like http://www.1001freefonts.com/rounded-fonts.php

[image: Helvetica rounded condensed]
<sub>(source: [fontshop.co.uk](https://www.fontshop.co.uk/preview/000175005.gif))</sub>

Comment: Are you only looking for a free option?

Comment: Right now i am yes.

Comment: Just remember that--at least for commercial projects--the time it takes to find alternatives sometimes exceeds the cost of just licensing the original font.

Comment: @DA01, hence the outsourcing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [BPreplay](http://www.dafont.com/bpreplay.font?text=WISER%20MAN%20box%20of%20tricks&back=theme)

[image: BPreplay font]

Not quite as condensed, but very similar

Comment: I actually decided to go with : http://www.fontspace.com/peter-wiegel/tgl, but your suggestion is very very close too. Thanks!

Comment: @OdifYltsaeb, you should post that as an answer and mark it as accepted if that's what you chose. No shame in answering your own question!

Answer (score 3):

Personally I love [VAG Rounded](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/vag-rounded/) (that's the font on the mac keyboards), but if you do want to convert the helvetica rounded to a webfont, try [font2web](http://www.font2web.com/)

Comment: You'd need a proper license to use Helvetica as a web font.